# Blank page displayed when accessing html file from local host in XAMPP

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, apache

I've been going mad for the last two days trying to understand why my localhost connection merely displays a blank page in any browser for my "index.html" file in my "htdocs" folder in XAMPP.  The page is blank in every browser (Edge, Chrome, Firefox, IE).  Strangely, I can view the source code fine for the page in the browser though!  Even more strangely, my "index.html" file displays a blank page *even when it's loaded from another location other than htdocs* (such as the desktop).  And my test html file I created displays just fine using the htdocs folder in XAMPP.  I'm using the default Apache ports 80 and 443.  I'm also using Windows 10.

Could this be some error in my webpage code?  I'm doing pretty vanilla stuff here: just CSS/HTML and Bootstrap.  All CSS/HTML/Bootstrap files are in the htdocs directory.  If you'd like to see the full code, you can go to my publicly hosted site at [stephengladwin.com](http://www.stephengladwin.com)  You can also view my current XAMPP code for my "index.html" file in the attached screenshot.

Here's what I've tried:
   -Unticking the "use ports 80 and 443" box in Skype
   -Re-installing XAMPP
   -Updating the config file to listen to a different port (used port "123")
   -tried disabling "World Wide Web Publishing Service" in services.msc

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

[XAMPP Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SPFa.png)

Answer (score 0):

The best question is the one you answer yourself!  Turns out it was a bootstrap error.  In the Chrome browser inspect tool I opened the console and lo and behold, there was an error where the browswer couldn't access the "tether.min.js" file which bootstrap requires.  Indeed I did have the tether file linked in my index.html file, but *it was not in the right order in the code flow.*  It had to come *before* the javascript  link.  Now my index.html page displays fine on the localhost via XAMPP!